# service '/v1/updateContext' not found error

Tags: fiware-orion

I have launched an instance using "orion-psb-image-R4.1" on Spain2. 
I can remote login and start the context broker like this: “/etc/init.d/contextBroker start”.

But when send a command

```
    (curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d @- | xmllint --format - ) <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<updateContextRequest>
  <contextElementList>
    <contextElement>
      <entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
        <id>Room1</id>
      </entityId>
      <contextAttributeList>
        <contextAttribute>
          <name>temperature</name>
          <type>float</type>
          <contextValue>23</contextValue>
        </contextAttribute>
        <contextAttribute>
          <name>pressure</name>
          <type>integer</type>
          <contextValue>720</contextValue>
        </contextAttribute>
      </contextAttributeList>
    </contextElement>
  </contextElementList>
  <updateAction>APPEND</updateAction>
</updateContextRequest>
EOF
```

there is always this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orionError>
  <code>400</code>
  <reasonPhrase>Bad Request</reasonPhrase>
  <details>service '/v1/updateContext' not found</details>
</orionError>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the broker:

```
contextBroker --version
```

To not recognize '/v1' it must be really old.
I would not encourage to use this old version of the broker but if you really need to use that exact version, try with '/ngsi10/updateContext' instead of '/v1/updateContext'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I dot need any particular version. I have done "yum install contextBroker" and then it cannot be started up any more. How can I get the newer working version? thanks again!

Comment: I'd suggest to deal with the new issue (*"it [Orion] cannot be started up any more"*) in a separate question post at SOF. Could you ask it as a new post, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your request is transformed (badly) during its travel (port forwarding or proxy). 
I had the same issue during setup of nginx_proxyPass to Orion Context broker.